# Typescript variable type specification

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a case where a variable could be type **A** or type **B**. Then using a `If` I know what type the variable is and I apply an appropriate response.

I got TSLINT errors.

```
function checkIfItsAString(foo: String | Number): boolean {
  return foo instanceof String;
}

function example2(foo: String | Number) {
  if (checkIfItsAString(foo)) {
    foo.charAt(5);

    return;
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

How can I say to typescript,

> starting now, this variable is of type "String"

Comment: Is `staticIsAnError` actually a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates)? Give a [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've added a generic, reproductible example

Comment: So it's *not* a type predicate. The compiler doesn't know you expect that check to narrow the type.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT you can cast it `x as ManuallyCastType` but I'd suggest using a type predicate `checkIfItsAString(foo: String | Number): foo is String` this way you don't have to manually tell the compiler every time by casting the value

Comment: Did you follow the link I posted?

Comment: hm my bad! @jonrsharpe and VLAZ this is a perfect answer. Thank you. Please post it as an answer I'll accept. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler can't infer anything useful from the `boolean` return type of `checkIfItsAString`; the *name* of that function tells other human readers of the code what you expect, but that doesn't help the compiler at all.

Instead, you need to be explicit that this is a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates), i.e. inform the compiler that it can use this to narrow the type of a variable based on the result. Instead of just `boolean`, it is going to return whether `foo is String`:

```
function checkIfItsAString(foo: String | Number): foo is String {
```

The actual implementation doesn't need to change, this is just extra information for the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a type predicate to have the compiler automatically narrow down the types. Your predicate already works, to make it a type predicate you just have to say what it implies about the value:

```js
function checkIfItsAString(foo: String | Number): foo is String {
//  tell the compiler true means it's a string -> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  return foo instanceof String;
}
```

This lets the compiler determine the type automatically:

```
function example2(foo: String | Number) {
  if (checkIfItsAString(foo)) { //foo is a String

    foo.charAt(5);

    return;
  }

  foo.toFixed(""); //foo is a Number
}
```

[Live demo on TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQwBYFMYGsCSY+cAzgIIDKcATglAOYAUYSSAXKlbQ6gD6oA5CAFsARlmoBKDiySoEJTjTr1UAb1CpU1LHAjU0s+VBJwAhrCxIwS7vQDcoAL6hQkWIhSosADzPCABwAbLAAmZlYOLhU+QRFxKXVNeRtGTBwCIlJKZQYIpElJJJAtLVkAOkwzajI4RgBWSUcQZK0dPQNmrRcWktQKuCQAMQQfLAATRlCm5yA)

Alternatively, you can use the `in` operator directly which will do type elimination from a list of types:

```js
function example2(foo: String | Number) {
  if ("charAt" in foo) {
  //   ^^^^^^ this only exists on String not on Number, so it's a String
    foo.charAt(5);

    return;
  }

  foo.toFixed(2); //a number, since it doesn't have "charAt"
}
```

[Live demo on TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgJgApg44AuRAZSgCcYwBzRAH0QDkRMAjZWgSkQBvALAAoRIhjBERAEQQAFuloBBKHKlJScQaImTEOgHRKV6ogFZ+AbnHjDiWsighaYOwYC+9gyahwAGIwqMgAJkQEtuJeQA)

This is more useful for one-off simpler checks, so you don't need an entire predicate to handle it. It can be used to narrow down types, if that is a use case. Here is a contrived example that uses `in` to eliminate types in several steps.

```
/* 
 * ake a Nnumber, String, array of Numbers, or the HTMLCollection array-like:
 * for Number - the value
 * for HTMLCollection - the length
 * for array of number - the sum + the length
 * for string - the length + the trimmed length
 */
function dummyExample(x : Number | String | Number[] | HTMLCollection) : number {
  if ("length" in x) { // String | Number[] | HTMLCollection
    let totalLength: number = x.length;

    if ("slice" in x) { // String | Number[]
      if ("reduce" in x) { // Number[]
        return x.reduce((a: number, b: Number) => a + b.valueOf(), 0) + length;
      } else { // String
        return x.trim().length + totalLength;
      }
    } else { // HTMLCollection
      return totalLength;
    }
  } else { // Number
    return x.valueOf();
  }
}
```

[Live demo on TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAExAWzQTwKIA8CGaADgDYCmAFLgFyIBy6ARmQE6IA+iAylCzGAHMO9JqwDaAXWEAJACoBZADIBhOCXLR4YAJSJaYUWwDeAWABQiRDGCIKAInKCoACztWkuXaYuXE5KIhQcFD4JIpkTs76hogAvIi4AHSOAi4A3ObmvlY29gDOJDAQZG78CV6IWdk5tnYsZKjFpR5eVdWI9VAgLB6J9Y2UFPjRaMwsADSIjLQMo6y6sQB8iPiIANRTiQBuoSBkAPLAFNqTAAy6Gynpbb4AvohkJHlkiN7tlp3dvbwwaMfJEVSznWgWCoXCkQyPmytxu90ez1eNw+ZC6PVBITCgOu0MQsJ88KeLzevk+6KSOxIe0OxyhlnxtyAA)